# How to remove all rows belonging to a particular group when only one row fulfills the condition in R?

Tags: r

Following is my sample data set:

```
> dput(lanec)
structure(list(vehicle.id = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L), frame.id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L), lane.change = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L), .Label = c(".", "yes"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("vehicle.id", 
"frame.id", "lane.change"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-26L))
```

The first column is the IDs of vehicles entering on a particular segment of a freeway. They were observed until they left the segment so each vehicle has different number of time frames in which it was observed. The frame numbers are given in `frame.id` column. The third column tells whether the vehicle changed the lane and in which frame.
In this sample data all except vehicle # 2 changed the lane. Vehicle # 5 changed the lane twice.

## Required

I want to identify which vehicles changed the lane and remove them from data set. I tried using `subset(lanec, lane.change!='yes')` but it only remove those rows where the value of `lane.change` is `yes`. Using the sample data set, the desired output should be:

```
vehicle.id frame.id lane.change
1           2        1           .
2           2        2           .
3           2        3           .
4           2        4           .
5           2        5           .
```

How can I achieve this? It must be simple but I can't figure it out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
subset(lanec, ave(lane.change != "yes", vehicle.id, FUN = all))
```

To help understand what `ave` returns, maybe you can break it into a couple steps:

```
lanec <- transform(lanec, stays.in.lane = ave(lane.change != "yes", vehicle.id, FUN = all))
subset(lanec, stays.in.lane)
```

You will see that `ave` returns a vector of TRUE/FALSE along `lanec`: whether the `vehicle.id` had all (hence the use of `all`) of its `lane.change` values not equal to `'yes'`.

Comment: Or `lanec[with(lanec, ave(lane.change != "yes", vehicle.id, FUN = all)),]` to avoid using `subset`

Comment: It's a matter of taste, I prefer using `subset` to avoid having to write `lanec` twice. I'm also using one fewer functions than you, it's more readable you could argue.

Comment: @flodel Thank you. It works. But could you please also explain what is happening in background? I looked at `ave` in help and found that it finds the mean by grouping variable. Two things are confusing me here: 1) I see that you replaced `mean` with `all` in `FUN`, what does that mean? 2) `lane.change` is a factor variable but `ave` finds the average, how does it work for factors?

Answer (score 0):

```
 steady <- names( which(with(lanec, tapply(lane.change, vehicle.id, function(x) all(x==".")) ) ))
steady
[1] "2"
```

So pick the onew where all the items in lane.change are "."

```
lanec[ lanec$vehicle.id %in% steady, ]
#-------

  vehicle.id frame.id lane.change
1          2        1           .
2          2        2           .
3          2        3           .
4          2        4           .
5          2        5           .
```